# pass data into/and start of new activity from listview item selection in alert dialog

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-alertdialog

In this app there is an alert dialog that pops up when either the left nav bar or action bar New List button is selected.  The alert dialog contains a list of created projects, so you have the option to select a project or to create a project.  The list of projects populate depending on what is in the SQLite database.

A little background, the main activity has a listview that displays a list of these same projects.  Currently I am able to select a project from the list, pass the row data, start a new activity, and populate text views in the new activity with the data from the selected project into another activity.

I need to do the same thing here, but from the alert dialog listview.  It needs to pass the project name into the newly started New List activity and display it either in the action bar or in a text view.

As you can see in the alert dialog for the left nav bar, if position 2 is selected the alert dialog comes up and the list populates from the database.  The displayToastForId(idInDB); works, so I know I am accessing the data.  When I try to use passListName(idInDB); it doesn't do anything.

I've searched and experimented for a week on this now.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Intent i;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");


    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    registerListClickCallbackMainList();
    try {
        openDB();
        populateProjects();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    i = new Intent(this, NewList.class);

}




//Starting New List activity and passing project name to edit text
public void passListName(long idInDB) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.getListInfo(idInDB);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String projectName = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_LIST_PROJECT_NAME);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("project_name", String.valueOf(projectName));
        startActivity(i);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
//end of passing data




/////////////////toast for item clicked on listview////////////////////
//gets all data from row clicked
public void displayToastForId(long idInDB) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.getProjectInfo(idInDB);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long idDB = cursor.getLong(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_ROWID);
        String project_name = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_NAME);
        String address = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_ADDRESS);
        String job_number = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_JOB_NUMBER);
        String site_contact = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_SITE_CONTACT);
        String phone = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_SITE_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String email = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_SITE_CONTACT_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

        String message = "ID: " + idDB + "\n"
                + "Size: " + project_name + "\n"
                + "Type: " + address + "\n"
                + "Length: " + job_number + "\n"
                + "Color: " + site_contact + "\n"
                + "Color: " + phone + "\n"
                + "Cut: " + email;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
/////////////////////end of toast for item clicked on listview//////////////////////




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//This code adds the drawer items to the left navigation bar.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Home", "Search", "New List", "New Project", "Reminders", "Preferences", "Help" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);


    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long id) {

            DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


            if (position == 0){
//Do nothing if left nav
            }
            if (position == 1){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Search.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 2){


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_custom_dialog, null);
                alertDialog.setView(convertView);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface alert, int which) {
//Do something here on click

                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewProject.class));
                        finish();
                        alert.dismiss();

                    }


                });
                alertDialog.setTitle("Select a Project");
                try{
                    openDB();


                } catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//Testing fetching projects info from database to populate list
                Cursor cursor1 = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.fetchProjectName();

                startManagingCursor(cursor1);


///setup mapping from cursor to view fields//////
                String[] fromDatabase = new String[]
                        {NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.KEY_PROJECT_NAME};

                int[] toList = new int[]
                        {R.id.alert_dialog_project_name};

////create adapter to map columns of database to rows in listview
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") final
                SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter1 =
                        new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                R.layout.main_activity_projects_alert_dialog_list_item,
                                cursor1,
                                fromDatabase,
                                toList,
                                0
                        );

                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter1);





                alertDialog.show();

                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                                            int position, long idInDB) {

                        try {
                            displayToastForId(idInDB);
                            //passListName(idInDB);




                             } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });


            }
            if (position == 3){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewProject.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 4){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Reminders.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 5){

            }
            if (position == 6){

            }
            if (position == 7){

            }
            if (position == 8){

            }

        }
    });
}

//End of adding items to left nav bar////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that seems to work.

Here are my two working activities now.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements          AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{


NewProjectDatabaseAdapter db;

public final static String ID_EXTRA="com.gofor.gofor._ID";
private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

Intent i;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");


    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    registerListClickCallbackMainList();
    try {
        openDB();
        populateProjects();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    i = new Intent(this, NewList.class);

}






public View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    }
};








//The method populates the current projects listview with the name of the project from the projects table
public void populateProjects() throws SQLException {
    try{
        openDB();
    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Cursor cursor1 = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.fetchProjectName();

    startManagingCursor(cursor1);


///setup mapping from cursor to view fields//////
    String[] fromDatabase = new String[]
            {NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.KEY_PROJECT_NAME};


    int[] toList = new int[]
            {R.id.project_name};


////create adapter to map columns of database to rows in listview//////
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") final
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter1 =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.main_activity_projects_list_item,
                    cursor1,
                    fromDatabase,
                    toList,
                    0
            );

    final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.projectListView);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter1);
    }
//End of populating projects list














/////////////////call back method for when list item is clicked from main activity main list////////////////////////////////
public void registerListClickCallbackMainList() {
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.projectListView);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                                int position, long idInDB) {

            try {
                displayToastForId(idInDB);
                passProjectInfo(idInDB);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
//////////////////////end of call back method for when the list item is clicked///////////////////////







/////////////////toast for item clicked on listview////////////////////
//gets all data from row clicked
public void displayToastForId(long idInDB) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.getProjectInfo(idInDB);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long idDB = cursor.getLong(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_ROWID);
        String project_name = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_NAME);
        String address = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_ADDRESS);
        String job_number = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_JOB_NUMBER);
        String site_contact = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_SITE_CONTACT);
        String phone = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_SITE_CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String email = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_SITE_CONTACT_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

        String message = "ID: " + idDB + "\n"
                + "Project: " + project_name + "\n"
                + "Address: " + address + "\n"
                + "Job#: " + job_number + "\n"
                + "Site Contact: " + site_contact + "\n"
                + "Phone: " + phone + "\n"
                + "Email: " + email;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
 /////////////////////end of toast for item clicked on listview//////////////////////







/////////////////starts new list activity and passes project name and rowid
public void passProjectName(long idInDB) throws SQLException {
    Cursor cursor = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.getProjectInfo(idInDB);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {


        long idDB = cursor.getLong(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_ROWID);
        String project_name = cursor.getString(NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.COL_PROJECT_NAME);

        i.putExtra("project_rowid", String.valueOf(idDB));
        i.putExtra("list_project_name", String.valueOf(project_name));
        startActivity(i);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
/////////////////////end of new list activity and passing projet name and rowid//////////////////////









////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//This code adds the drawer items to the left navigation bar.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Home", "Search", "New List", "New Project", "Reminders", "Preferences", "Help" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);


    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, final long id) {

            DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


            if (position == 0){
//Do nothing if left nav
            }
            if (position == 1){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Search.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 2){


                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_custom_dialog, null);
                alertDialog.setView(convertView);
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface alert, int which) {
//Do something here on click

                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewProject.class));
                        finish();
                        alert.dismiss();

                    }


                });
                alertDialog.setTitle("Select a Project");
                try{
                    openDB();


                } catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
//Testing fetching projects info from database to populate list
                Cursor cursor1 = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.fetchProjectName();

                startManagingCursor(cursor1);


///setup mapping from cursor to view fields//////
                String[] fromDatabase = new String[]
                        {NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.KEY_PROJECT_NAME};

                int[] toList = new int[]
                        {R.id.alert_dialog_project_name};

////create adapter to map columns of database to rows in listview
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") final
                SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter1 =
                        new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                R.layout.main_activity_projects_alert_dialog_list_item,
                                cursor1,
                                fromDatabase,
                                toList,
                                0
                        );

                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter1);





                alertDialog.show();



                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                                            int position, long idInDB) {
                        try {
                            //displayToastForId(idInDB);
                            passProjectName(idInDB);
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });


            }
            if (position == 3){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewProject.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 4){
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Reminders.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 5){

            }
            if (position == 6){

            }
            if (position == 7){

            }
            if (position == 8){

            }

        }
    });
}

//End of adding items to left nav bar////////////////////////////////////////




//Setting up the drawer for opening and closing the left nav bar
private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Choose One");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

/** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
//getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
//End of setting up drawer for opening and closing the left nav bar










@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
// Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//This is the action bar new list icon
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_newlist:

//If the new list icon is selected bring up alert dialog  and populates the list of projects inside.
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_custom_dialog, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface alert, int which){
//Do something here on click
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewProject.class));
                    finish();
                    alert.dismiss();
                }

            });
            alertDialog.setTitle("Select a Project");

            try{
                openDB();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//Testing fetching projects info from database to populate list

            Cursor cursor1 = NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.fetchProjectName();

            startManagingCursor(cursor1);


///setup mapping from cursor to view fields//////
            String[] fromDatabase = new String[]
                    {NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.KEY_PROJECT_NAME};


            int[] toList = new int[]
                    {R.id.alert_dialog_project_name};


////create adapter to map columns of database to rows in listview//////
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") final
            SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter1 =
                    new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                            this,
                            R.layout.main_activity_projects_alert_dialog_list_item,
                            cursor1,
                            fromDatabase,
                            toList,
                            0
                    );


            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter1);







//on item click listener for the alert dialog listview of projects
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                                        int position, long idInDB) {


//                        try {
//                            passListName(idInDB);
//                        } catch (SQLException e) {
//                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        }
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
//End of action bar new list icon selection.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
//End of on options item selected///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////






//This method creates a new instance of open database method in NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.java
private void openDB() throws SQLException {
    db = new NewProjectDatabaseAdapter(this);
    NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.open();
}
//End of open database method







@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}






@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

NewList.java

```
public class NewList extends ActionBarActivity implements     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

Button Done, Cancel;
EditText sqlNewListProjectName, sqlNewListName, sqlNewListDate, sqlNewListTime,
        sqlNewListMethod, sqlNewListNotes;


private ListView mDrawerList;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private String mActivityTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_list);


    Done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_list_done_button);
    Cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_list_cancel_button);
    //sqlNewListProjectName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_list_project_name);
    sqlNewListName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_list_list_name);
    sqlNewListDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_list_date);
    sqlNewListTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_list_time);
    sqlNewListNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_list_notes);


    Done.setOnClickListener(this);
    Cancel.setOnClickListener(this);


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("New List");


    mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

    addDrawerItems();
    setupDrawer();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);




    String project_rowid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("project_rowid");
    String project_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("list_project_name");

    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_list_project_name);
    tv1.setText(project_name);

    Toast.makeText(NewList.this, project_rowid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //TODO Auto generated method stub

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.new_list_done_button:

            boolean didItWork = true;
            try {

//This is pulling the text entered from the text fields for the new project, creating strings
// from them and entering them into the projects table
                String projectName = sqlNewListProjectName.getText().toString();
                String listName = sqlNewListName.getText().toString();
                String listDate = sqlNewListDate.getText().toString();
                String listTime = sqlNewListTime.getText().toString();
                //String listMethod = sqlNewListMethod.getText().toString();
                String listNotes = sqlNewListNotes.getText().toString();

                NewProjectDatabaseAdapter entry = new NewProjectDatabaseAdapter(NewList.this);
                NewProjectDatabaseAdapter.open();
                entry.createEntry(projectName, listName, listDate, listTime,
                        //listMethod,
                        listNotes);
                entry.close();


            } catch (Exception e ){
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Nope!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();

            }finally {
                if (didItWork) {


                    Toast.makeText(this, "List Created!" + '\n' + '\n' + sqlNewListName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startActivity(new Intent(NewList.this, Search.class));


                }
            }

            break;
        case R.id.new_list_cancel_button:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewList.this);
            builder.setMessage("Cancel and go Home?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            startActivity(new Intent(NewList.this, MainActivity.class));
//                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
//                                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                            //call this when ready to exit dialog
                            //NewProject.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            //call this when ready to exit dialog
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

//                Intent i = new Intent("com.gofor.gofor.SQLView");
//                startActivity(i);
//                break;
    }
}

public View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }
};





private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Home", "Search", "New List", "New Project", "Reminders", "Preferences", "Help" };
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);


    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Search.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                //Do nothing
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewProject.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Reminders.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            if (position == 5) {

            }
            if (position == 6) {

            }
            if (position == 7) {

            }
            if (position == 8) {

            }

        }
    });
}



private void setupDrawer() {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Choose One");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            //getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


    // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_home:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(NewList.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(NewList.this, Search.class));
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

}


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

}
```